# Get up-sell product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, object-manager, up-sells

I am trying to get up-sell product in Magento 2 via objectManager. Current product id and name is returning well but up-sell product return empty.

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    echo $product->getId();
    echo $product->getName();
    //echo $currentProduct->getSku();
if ($currentProduct = $product->getCurrentProduct()) {
    $upSellProducts = $currentProduct->getUpSellProducts();
    print_r($upSellProducts);

    if (!empty($upSellProducts)) {
        echo '<h3>UpSell Products</h3>';
        foreach ($upSellProducts as $upSellProduct) {
            echo $upSellProduct->getSku() . '<br />';        
        }
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By Factory Method:**

```
protected $_registry;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    ...
) {
    $this->_registry = $registry;
}

public function getCurrentProduct()
{
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
}

public function getUpsellProducts()
{
    $currentProduct = $this->getCurrentProduct();
    $upsellProducts = $currentProduct->getUpSellProducts();

    return $upsellProducts;
}
```

**By ObjectManager:**

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currentProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product

if ($currentProduct) {

    $upsellProducts = $currentProduct->getUpSellProducts();

    if (!empty($upsellProducts)) {
        echo '<h3>UpSell Products</h3>';
        foreach ($upsellProducts as $upsellProduct) {
            echo $id = $upSellProduct->getSku();
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: With this code, you cannot get full model of product. For that, you need to load product model by upsell product Id.

Comment: Well great@@ but this code only fetch up-sell product sku, it's does not show  full product

Comment: Prince Patel@ you there?

Comment: @sanjay you can get all data from $product object, check my answer

Comment: Prince Patel@ please see the updated question after use your code@ you are awesome  doing great. but I am looking up-sell product  with default view .

Comment: Prince Patel@youthere?

Comment: @sanjay Here,  just code of getting upsell product data. you can create html from this code as you like. Also default Magento 2  provide upsell product block in product page.

Comment: ok thanku@any other help bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60118/discussion-between-sanjay-and-prince-patel).

Comment: @PrincePatel, I have got upsell products as per your code. Now  I also need to get special price and rating of the upsell products.

Comment: Can I get Name and image of the upsell product using above code

Comment: @Sri No, you have to load product model by upsell product Id.

Comment: Thank you @PrincePatel. I have loaded the upsell product Id and get the Name and Image.

Comment: But I have got 2 products from upsell collection, I got the name and image. But while getting producturl and ProductPrice it shows same url and price for both of the 2 items

Comment: @sri plz post a new question to make clean communication in this answer and past new question link here I will help you :)

Comment: Hi how to get upsell products collection like in view page, wish to display only the instock products

Comment: Wish to get upsell product collection with instock filter

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
echo $product->getId();
echo $product->getName();
//echo $currentProduct->getSku();
if ($currentProduct = $product) {
    $upSellProducts = $currentProduct->getUpSellProducts();
    //print_r($upSellProducts);

    if (!empty($upSellProducts)) {
        echo '<h3>UpSell Products</h3>';
        foreach ($upSellProducts as $upSellProduct) {
            echo $upSellProduct->getSku() . '<br />';        
        }
    }
}
```